# get value of window resize function and take it in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

following situation:

```
var height = $(window).height();
$(window).resize(function() {
var getfactor1 = 680 / 697
var posval1 = height*getfactor1
});
```

and in another function i have the following:

```
if($firstBG.hasClass("inview")){
$firstBG.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos(0, windowHeight, pos, posval1, 0.3)});   
    }
```

how can i get the value of posval1 in the window.resize() function into the firstBG.css everytime the user scales the browser window.

thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try to pass it trough a function:

```
var height = $(window).height();
 $(window).resize(function() {
 var getfactor1 = 680 / 697
 var posval1 = height*getfactor1

 myFunction(posval1);

});

 function myFunction(posval1){
  if($firstBG.hasClass("inview")){
   $firstBG.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos(0, windowHeight, pos, posval1, 0.3)});   
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, easier, why don't you declare posval1 outside the windows resize function?

```
var height = $(window).height(),
    posval1;

$(window).resize(function() {
   var getfactor1 = 680 / 697;
   posval1 = height*getfactor1;
});

if($firstBG.hasClass("inview")){
    $firstBG.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos(0, windowHeight, pos, posval1, 0.3)});   
}
```

Comment: you didnt get my point, i need the value of posval1 in the window resize function. how should the if firstBG class get the value out of the resize function?

Comment: The problem here is that the posval1 variable is declared inside the window resize function, so it's valid and accessible ONLY INSIDE this function. If you declare the posval1 OUTSIDE the two functions, its scope becomes general, and you'll be able to access (when I say access I mean read and write) it from both.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't put the $firstBG.css() into the window.resize()?

Comment: because its in another function!

Answer (score 0):

The resize event happens every time the user resizes the window. If you want to change something, it must be done from the handler for that event, otherwise the values will not update. But generally, if you have the `posval1` variable in a higher scope than the resize event handler, you can access it from other places too, but as I said, the other parts of the code will not execute again unless in the event handler.

Scope example:

```
var posval1;

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  posval1 = height * (680 / 697);
});

// somewhere else
console.log(posval1);
```

The value of `posval1` is most likely to be undefined at the time the execution reaches `console.log()` however, because the window was not resized yet. What you *could* do is just outsource the CSS update to another function, and call it from the event handler as well as once at the start.

```
var windowHeight, pos, posval1; // etc

var updateBg = function () {
  if($firstBG.hasClass("inview")){
    $firstBG.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos(0, windowHeight, pos, posval1, 0.3)});   
  }
};

updateBg(); // once

$(window).on('resize', function () {
  // calculate posval1
  updateBg(); // every time on resize
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this seems logical to me but i cant get it to work... i will post another answer with the fullcode!

Answer (score 0):

```
function newPos(x, windowHeight, pos, adjuster, inertia){
    return x + "% " + (-((windowHeight + pos) - adjuster) * inertia)  + "px";
}



function Move(){ 
    var pos = $window.scrollTop(); 


    if($firstBG.hasClass("inview")){
         var getfactor1 = 680/697;
        var posval1 = height*getfactor1;
        console.log(posval1);
        $firstBG.css({'backgroundPosition': newPos(0, windowHeight, pos, posval1, 0.3)});   
    }



    if($secondBG.hasClass("inview")){   
        var getfactor2 = 1255/697;
        var posval2 = height*getfactor2;
```

....... and so on